# Upload multiple files to server through WCF Service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

As per requirement, I want to upload multiple files to Server from a windows application.  I am planning to use a WCF service to upload the files. Is there any other better approach?
If possible please provide me the code samples.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Not helpful.  We all started somewhere and we all like "code samples" when studying a new API otherwise it makes it all the more difficult.  SO should not turn people away if people perceive them as doing a _homework assignment_

Comment: @JohnSaunders Your point?  I learnt 6809E from a book and published a game.  The book had code samples.  Today samples and APIs are online.  The Internet may be amazing but "browsing" for information is becoming harder, one must know _what to Google for_.  It can be hard if you don't know the keywords.  I miss flicking through the pages of the Encyclopedia Britannica.  At least books were friendly and tried to help the reader. Unlike the online community. And don't make assumptions about my age

Comment: @MickyDuncan: I said nothing about your age. I spoke about people who fish for code samples instead of learning to fish for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually rather easy and does not require the purchase of a 3rd party product or subscription, let alone a cloud service.

Consider this article from MSDN:

> *Sometimes developers must have full control of how data is returned from a service operation. This is the case when a service operation must return data in a format not supported byWCF. This topic discusses using the WCF REST Programming Model to create a service that receives arbitrary data.* [How to: Create a Service That Accepts Arbitrary Data using the WCF REST Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

WCF actually allows you to specify a **Stream** type for a service method.

Here is how to define the service interface (extract from above link):

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IReceiveData
 {
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}")]
    void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents);
 }
```

The implementation looks as below: (again from the above article)

```
public class RawDataService : IReceiveData
{
public void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
    int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead > 0);
    Console.WriteLine("Service: Received file {0} with {1} bytes", fileName, totalBytesRead);
}
```

}

[Read more...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Maybe try [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/), to expedite the process, the $50 dollar license cost a year is worth the pain and hassle, gives you are nice front end and FineUploader managers multiple uploads for you and you just setup a single file upload service. I am in no way affiliated with Fine Uploader, just like the product, and used it to provide multiple file uploads pretty quickly. You may also consider Telerik's Kendo UI file uploader, Telerik has made Telerik Kendo UI Core free recently.

Comment: -1 I disagree.  Once you grasp the basics of WCF it's an easy step to any of the EAI or SOA patterns.  http://www.soapatterns.org/ http://www.eaipatterns.com/  Also I'm not sure if the OP wants to pay for a cloud service

Comment: Still low cost and highly effective solution suggestions that also knock out all U.I. front end aspects.